# Probability of coin flips

Tags: probability

Just wanted to double check some things for this question:

Flip a coin three times the outcome can be summerized into 4 events

- x = the number of times heads comes up is ODD,
- y = the number of times heads comes up is EVEN,
- z = the number of times tails comes up is ODD,
- w = the number of times tails comes up is EVEN.

• Determine $Pr(x)$, $Pr(y)$, $Pr(z)$, $Pr(w)$, $Pr(x | y)$, and $Pr(z | w)$.

• Are there any two events that are independent?

Heres what I got:

There are $2^3=8$ possible outcomes for flipping a coin three times I define a set $S = { HHH, HHT, HTH, HTT, THH, THT, TTH, TTT }$

- $PR(x)=4/8=2/4$
- $PR(y)=3/8$
- $PR(z)=4/8=2/4$
- $PR(w)=3/8$

I have determined that $(x\cap z)$ is 0 and $(x\cap w)$ is $3/8$
Therefore $Pr(x|z)=Pr(x\cap z)/Pr(z)=0/(2/4)=0$ and $Pr(x|w)=Pr(x\cap w)/Pr(w)=(3/8)/(3/8)=1$.

In terms of what two events are independent I think none of them are.

Comment: Note that $0$ is even. We have $\Pr(y)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Count them again:
$$\begin{array}{|l:l|c:c|} \hline
& & \rm HHH & \rm HHT & \rm HTH & \rm THH & \rm HTT & \rm THT & \rm TTH & \rm TTT \\ \hline
x & \text{Heads Are Odd} & \checkmark &  & & & \checkmark  & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\
y & \text{Heads Are Even} & & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark  
\\
z & \text{Tails Are Odd} & & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark  \\
w & \text{Tails Are Even} & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark  \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: Thanks for the tip I forgot that 0 is a even number. I have made adjustments to my calculations and got 0 for $PR(x|z)$ and 1 for $Pr(x|w)$. I still don't think that any two events are independent.